# Filter row values based on if the column related to this row is existent in another table

Tags: sql

I have a table A with the following columns,

```
Name| Product_Id| 
----|-----------|
1   | 100       | 
1   | 300       | 
1   | 500       | 
2   | 600       | 
2   | 700       | 
2   | 800       | 
2   | 900       |
```

There is another table B, that might or might not contain all the product_Ids mentioned above.

```
| Product_Id| 
|-----------|
| 100       | 
| 300       | 
| 500       |
```

Now my desired result should be the 'Name' that has NONE of its products existing in Table B,
Expected result:

```
|2
```

> Note: If '2' had even a single 'Product_Id' that also existed in Table B, then it does not qualify to be in the results.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server,` etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select Name
 from table_a
 where Product_Id
 not in (
       select Product_Id
       from table_b
 )
 group by Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cte` :

```
with t as (
     select t.Name, t.Product_Id, t1.Product_Id as Avail_Product_Id
     from table t left join
          table2 t1
          on t1.Product_Id = t.Product_Id
)

select distinct t.Name
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t1 where t.Name = t1.Name and t1.Avail_Product_Id is not null);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `not in`

```
 select distinct name from TableA 
where Product_Id not in (select Product_Id from tableB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using `IN`

```
SELECT tA.Name
FROM tableA tA
LEFT JOIN tableB tB ON tB.Product_Id = tA.Product_Id
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` too

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name
FROM table_a a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_b b
    WHERE b.Product_Id = a.Product_Id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE(Name INT, Product_Id INT)
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES
(1 ,100 ), 
(1 ,300 ),
(1 ,500 ),
(1 ,800 ),
(2 ,600 ),
(2 ,700 ),
(2 ,800 ),
(2 ,900 )


DECLARE @TableB TABLE(Product_Id INT)
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES
(100), 
(300), 
(500)

SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM @TableA A 
WHERE Name NOT IN (
    SELECT Name FROM @TableA A 
    WHERE A.Product_Id IN (SELECT Product_Id FROM @TableB) 
)
```

Result:

```
Name
-----------
2
```